# Weird SQL request(Join)

Tags: sql, select, join, sql-server-2000

Assuming there are two tables A={a,b} and B={0,1,2}, which can be joined

```
tableA  tableB
a       0
b       1
a       2
        3
```

How to get the following result
ExpectingResult:

```
tableA  tableB
a-------0
b-------1
null----2
null----3
```

OR

```
   tableA   tableB
    a-------2
    b-------3
    null----0
    null----1
```

Just make sure the element in each table just appear once, I tried all kinds of join(inner, full, cross), none of them can achieve so. Could anybody give me a tip?

Thank you very much

Please check this link out to the question itself: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fc21/2

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Under what criteria are you matching `a` with `0` and not with `1`?

Comment: just suppose those two tables can be joined.  whatever it is a with 0 or 1, I just want it can be distincted. I don't want a-0, a-1, a-2, b-0, b-1, b-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That **is** a crappy request. There is almost negligible reasons for producing such an output that comes to mind, although I'm not ruling out a sane reason completely.

For SQL Server 2000, you will need to go through temp tables to get a sequential key to zip up with.

```
  SELECT IDENTITY(int,1,1) ID, Value
    INTO #tblA
    FROM tableA
ORDER BY Value;

  SELECT IDENTITY(int,1,1) ID, Value
    INTO #tblB
    FROM tableB
ORDER BY Value;

  SELECT A.Value, B.Value
    FROM #tblA A FULL OUTER JOIN #tblB B ON A.ID = B.ID
ORDER BY Coalesce(A.ID, B.ID);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I am very appreciate it.

Comment: I think my description is not very clear. The join condition is not unique, so cannot assign them with an unique ID to join them. Suppose their join conditions are same value, can you distinct the result?

Comment: @user1874700 - The whole purpose of adding the `IDENTITY` *(ROWNUM)* is to make each row unique. Did you try it? Did you try the [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbb34/2) I've set up?

Comment: I newly setup a new table, which exactly is the question itself, please have a look. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13294/8

Comment: Have you even tried my query with very little change (just field name from value->achar and value->anumber)? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13294/10/2

Comment: If you have time, please visit the full version of this question. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fc21/2

Answer (score 0):

Using `SQL Server 2005`, you can use a combination of `ROW_NUMBER` and a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to combine both results.

See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbb34/2)

Unfortunately, `SQL Server 2000` doesn't have a `ROW_NUMBER` function so you are kind of stuck with using temporary tables with identity fields to simulate a rownumber.

The gist of this would be to

- Select your required data from tableA into #tempTableA, adding an identity field.
- Repeat for tableB
- Use the temptables to `FULL OUTER JOIN` the results

Comment: Thank you Lieven, I just rewrite the question, Sry for the confusion

Comment: Hi Lieven, do you mind check this link and modify the query please.http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13294/8